# Grid with multiple Resource Models

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, admin-controller, router

I'm trying to use one grid for multiple ResourceModels, so far I've got one grid working fine.

I can load the grid up fine using **http:{}/admin/grid/grid/**
[image]

However when i create a new route to load the same controller:
**http:{}/admin/grid2/grid/** . I get no main block content
[image]

[image]

Here's my component UI based grid setup: Works fine for route /admin/grid/grid.

[image]

Does anyone know if i need to duplicate some files/directories to get grid2 to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create  **grid2_grid_index.xml** file under layout same as **grid_grid_index.xml**

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy only `layout` file, due to 'grid2' route already mentioned in `routes.xml`.

You need to create only `grid2_grid_index.xml`.
copy `grid_grid_index.xml` to `grid2_grid_index.xml` you can call same `ui_component` file in that layout.xml file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't need to copy the controller to make the grid show, is there some other functionality that needs a copied controller file?

Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Index.php sets the title via resultFactoy->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend('Grid List'), Http://{}/admin/grid2/grid has "Grid List" Title

Comment: then how your layout file called which `grid2_grid_index.xml` ?

Comment: I know UI-Component is loaded this way, but Grid2_grid_index.xml must be built in... Di.xml -> <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="grid_record_grid_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">

Comment: This code is for loading data collection

Comment: grid2_grid_index.xml is built in Magento2 pathing I think. Things work fine..

Comment: no that is not like that layout file will create based on your id of route then your directory and then your action file so it will not work without creating controller file

Comment: Oh I got it you have created two routes . so you don't need to create controller file !! yes it will be worked cheers +1